# How to set user's permission using custom form in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom FORM in a wordpress template, this form (with users/pwd) will check if the users is registered or not (in a custom mysql table, **NOT** in wp_users).

If the login succeded i need to set a custom WORDPRESS permission (role) to that user...
how can i force it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new User Role, I recommend using [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/), but there are a few of them.

A function to GET the role translated.

```
// Returns the current user role translated, i.e. 'Administrator'. Case sensitive!
function get_current_user_role() {
    global $wp_roles;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = $current_user->roles;
    $role = array_shift($roles);
    return isset($wp_roles->role_names[$role]) ? translate_user_role($wp_roles->role_names[$role] ) : false;
}
```

Using the above function, to deploy in your php:

```
function userRoleCheck() {
    global $current_user;

     $userRole = get_current_user_role();

     if ($userRole == 'Administrator') {
              // Allowed
          } else {
             // Not allowed.
     }
```

Please view [How to add a user role programmatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4725/how-to-change-a-users-role).

Comment: I CAN'T use this kind of code, as I wrote above, the users  is NOT saved in the WP_USERS mysql table, it is stored in a custom user table (no WP related). I have this table in the same database where i have all the WP tables, but I Must to store these kind of users in that table) using wp_get_current_user() function I will get the logged using the default WP user table. Understand? I need to set a role to an user (forcing that role in the session of the user)